# Where to write GWT -noserver option to avoid jetty?

Tags: tomcat, gwt

For some reason I need my GWT application to start over a tomcat server. I did as follows:
1) I installed WTP for eclipse
2) Configured tomcat 7 as a server which is up and running
3) Create a dynamic web project and migrate my GWT app
Now i don't know where to write *-noserver* option and i couldn't find a clear step-by-step instruction over the internet.
Can someone please guide me through the way to run GWT in debugging mode over tomcat?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Are the instructions in the [GWT's FAQ](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging.html#How_do_I_use_my_own_server_in_development_mode_instead_of_GWT's) not sufficient?

> 1. Configure your server however you need to; note the URL which contains the host page for your GWT application.
> 2. Arrange all your static content files (such as the host HTML page, images, CSS, etc.) on the server however you like.
> 3. Edit your development mode execution script (such as your Eclipse run configuration or the ant development build target generated by the GWT webAppCreator) and add or update the following options:
>
>    - Add the -noserver command line argument.
>    - Change the URL at the end of the argument list to match the URL you recorded in step #1.
> 4. Compile your application once using the ant build target. Ideally, you can use GWT's -war option to generate output files directly into your external server's static content folder. Otherwise, you'll need to copy the GWT output folder from war/ to your external server's static content.

If you're using the [Google Plugin for Eclipse](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/running_and_debugging_2_0), the setting you are looking for is in the **Server** tab in your run configuration:

[image: Server tab in run configuration]

Deselect it and it should add the `-noserver` parameter automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as Igor Klimer said, the answer is mentioned in the Google's guide but is not really clear enough. For the ones who has difficulties to understand what Google said in the guide and still don't know where to put the ***-noserver*** option, please follow these steps:

1) In **Run Configuration** window select the configuration which your project uses to run.
2) Select **Arguments** tab.
3) Write ***-noserver*** option in **Program Arguments** box
4) Apply

It's done!  :)